# Get Mystery Character's ord() value in PHP

Tags: php, unicode

I have a strange space character in that somehow got inserted into my database. I would like to know what this possibly unicode character is but I'm running into some problems. For example:

I have the string " " where the seemingly ordinary space is the mystery character". I then want to get it's `ord()` value. If I do `echo ord(' ');` I get 194 which is not correct. I know that it is some kind of unicode character because if I do `echo strlen(' ');` I get `2` back.

I need to know this characters unicode value so I can do a MYSQL query to get rid of it once and for all in my DB. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [php docs](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php), ord() returns the ASCII-value of a character. If you know your character is not ASCII, this function is not what you're looking for. I would try to echo the character (make sure you use UTF-8 as charset for the connection), copy it and paste it to http://unicodelookup.com/ to see what this character is about.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run `echo '0x' . bin2hex( $mystery_character );` and google the result.

Search for it in MySQL:

`SELECT col FROM table WHERE col LIKE CONCAT('%', CHAR(0xc2a0), '%')`

Replacing it to regular space:

`UPDATE table SET col = REPLACE(col, CHAR(0xc2a0), ' ')`

Comment: Turns out it's 0xc2a0 which is some kind of non-breaking space. So my next question is how to use MySQL to query for that?

Comment: @kriz - this kind of thing comes from "the real world" - and simply replacing values on a one off basis isn't the answer - there are many different spaces that the Unicode standard allows for, and, as soon as you cleanse your data of one, you'll find another one creeps in. Better to make your software work with uncode, usually acheived with utf16 or utf8.